# Как вывести адрес элемента в массиве, если его значение 35?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Есть алгоритм программы:

1. Создать массив 6х6.
2. Вывести адреса всех элементов в массиве.
3. Вывести адреса элементов, значение которых 35.

Вопрос возник при выполнение 3 алгоритма, программа выводит вместо адресов пустые строки.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{

    int *a;
    int i, j, n = 6, m = 6;
    a = (int*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));
    printf("Array[6][6]:\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            *(a + i*n + j) = rand() % 36;
            if (!a)
                printf("Array not was created!");
            else
                printf("%4d", *(a + i*n + j));
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("\nAddress of the array a[] \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d:%d] [%d] \n ", i, j, a[i*n + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nAddress of the element with value 35 in array a[] \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (*(a + i*n + j) == '35')
                printf("[%d:%d] [%d] \n ", i, j, a[i*n + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (*(a + i*n + j) == '35')
```

Вот эта строчка и компилироваться-то не должна. Ошибка вот тут `'35'`. Здесь не нужны кавычки вообще, тем более синтаксически неверные одинарные кавычки.
Ну и выводите Вы индексы элементов, а не их адреса.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в задании сказано:

> 1.Создать массив 6х6

Однако вы в программе не создаете такой массив. Поэтому программа изначально не соответствует требованиям задания.

Имейте в виду, что функция `main`  в C должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
```

Также для вывода адресов используется спецификатор формата `%p`

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N   6
#define MAX_VALUE   36

int main( void )
{
    int a[N][N];
    int i, j, l;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nArray[%d][%d]:\n\n", N, N );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }


    printf("\nAddresses of the elements of array a[] \n\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%p ", ( void * )&a[i][j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }


    printf("\nAddresses of elements with value %d in array a[] \n\n", MAX_VALUE - 1 );

    l = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[i][j] == MAX_VALUE - 1 )
            {
                l = 1;               
                printf( "&a[%d][%d] = %p\n", i, j, ( void * )&a[i][j] );
            }                
        }
    }

    if ( l == 0 ) printf( "There are no elements with the value %d\n", MAX_VALUE - 1 );

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
Array[6][6]:

14 10 27 15 29 35 
22  8 15  8 12 31 
23 34  7 34 28  0 
 6 23 35 21  6 15 
19 17  1 28  9 11 
 8  3 21 35 19 14 

Addresses of the elements of array a[] 

0x7ffcd5be8080 0x7ffcd5be8084 0x7ffcd5be8088 0x7ffcd5be808c 0x7ffcd5be8090 0x7ffcd5be8094 
0x7ffcd5be8098 0x7ffcd5be809c 0x7ffcd5be80a0 0x7ffcd5be80a4 0x7ffcd5be80a8 0x7ffcd5be80ac 
0x7ffcd5be80b0 0x7ffcd5be80b4 0x7ffcd5be80b8 0x7ffcd5be80bc 0x7ffcd5be80c0 0x7ffcd5be80c4 
0x7ffcd5be80c8 0x7ffcd5be80cc 0x7ffcd5be80d0 0x7ffcd5be80d4 0x7ffcd5be80d8 0x7ffcd5be80dc 
0x7ffcd5be80e0 0x7ffcd5be80e4 0x7ffcd5be80e8 0x7ffcd5be80ec 0x7ffcd5be80f0 0x7ffcd5be80f4 
0x7ffcd5be80f8 0x7ffcd5be80fc 0x7ffcd5be8100 0x7ffcd5be8104 0x7ffcd5be8108 0x7ffcd5be810c 

Addresses of elements with value 35 in array a[] 

&a[0][5] = 0x7ffcd5be8094
&a[3][2] = 0x7ffcd5be80d0
&a[5][3] = 0x7ffcd5be8104
```

Имейте в виду, что чаще всего массив не будет содержать элементы со значением 35, так как они маловероятны.

Comment: А зачем int main( void ) так? Ведь это ж главная функция...

Comment: @nicolia В C объявления int f( void ) и int f() имеют разное семантическое значение. Стандарт C требует, чтобы функция main без параметров был объявлена так, как я вам показал.

Comment: А зачем тут void *?

Comment: @nicolia Некоторые компиляторы требует, что когда выводится указатель с использованием спецификатора %p, чтобы указатель имел тип void * Можете его удалить, если ваш компилятор будет компилировать код без предупреждений.

Answer (score 0):

Я, пожалуй, обобщу ответы выше. Vlad from Moscow неправ, когда говорит, что автор вопроса не создаёт такой массив. Создаёт, правда весьма оригинальным образом. Вот создание:

```
a = (int*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));
```

Я думаю, что автор знает, как сделать это правильнее, но просто захотел извращений, потому что такую конструкцию мог написать только человек, которому известны тонкости языка C и особенности представления данных в оперативной памяти.

А по сути вопроса я думаю, что andy.37 прав. Нужно лишь убрать кавычки и программа заработает.

Vlad from Moscow, судя по коду автора, он имел в виду индексы массива, а не адреса в памяти.

Comment: Двумерный и одномерный массивы - это разные типы. Так что ваши комментарии ошибочны. Надо писать программу так, как указано в задании, а не заниматься "извращениями". И надо не комментарии в ответах писать, а давать собственные ответы на заданные вопросы.